# query on self defined variable

Tags: mysql, database, data-manipulation

How do I query on a self-defined variable?
Example:

```
SELECT *, MID(dateandtime, 12, 2) as 'xxx'
FROM xyz
WHERE year = '18-19'
AND xxx > 18
```

Is there a way to use xxx in the query like in the last line of the example?

Comment: Use the HAVING clause.

Comment: You are right! Searched for that, but could not find it. Therefore the question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly single quotes work just fine for column aliases. Though I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Woops, I learn something every day. Never even tried to do that so sorry

Comment: @RiggsFolly You will probably only find it debugging beginner code. So you missed nothing important :-)